# Create vertically responsive header

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[This guy](http://pjrvs.com/) has a header image that automatically fits *vertically* to whatever dimensions are above the fold in your particular browser when you first view his site.

How does he do this? An example (Fiddle) would be great, if possible.

Is this possible with just HTML and CSS?

Comment: Why don't you just view the source code and see how they did it?

Comment: Yep, pretty straight forward.

Comment: Sorry guys - I'm a beginner. Been looking at the code, but I can't figure it out

Comment: Question still stands - if anybody's got an answer for a beginner, that would great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my site, and I used the script from here: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/